# My chain on my 9 speed is slipping

Tags: chain

My chain on 9 speed is slipping. I measured my chain but the slipping continues. [image: slipping chain]

Comment: Is it a new chain? Has it been working and then suddenly started slipping  or have you changed something and the problem developed?

Comment: Too little info. When it happens, what is the front and rear gear you are using? Did it slipped on the largest cog or smallest cog? What happens to your derailer?

Comment: ...and what was the result of the measurement?

Comment: What have you changed lately ?  Was it a sudden change or a slow worsening ?

Comment: Unfortunately, your picture neatly avoids showing us stuff.  The shift cable is right in the critical point of the picture, so we can't tell why the chain is rising up off the cog.  Ones first suspicion would be a worn-out chain, but the cogs don't seem very worn (or even dirty, for that matter).  (But it may well be that the chain has died from lack of lubrication or from over-washing.)

Comment: I measured the chain and it has not been stretched then I adjusted the derailleur.  Rode today and no slipping.  Thanks this was my first time and my first bike; I am not knowledgeable.

Answer (score 1):

By the look of things, you may have the cable a very little bit too tight.

In other words, after you have gear down, the cable is still pulling just enough to want to go further (in the direction of the spokes), which causes the chain to ride up on the gear teeth.

Adjusting the cable adjuster (sometimes it's located right where the cable meats the derailleur) a 1/4 turn to loosen (make longer) the cable, should be enough to drop it back over the teeth.

This off coarse is assuming that by your description the cassette and chain are not worn or have not be independently replaced.